# Python script on EC2 returns wrong signature type error

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, openssl

I'm coding a discord bot in python. Whenever I try to connect to a specific site, on my EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2, the script returns the following error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientConnectorSSLError: Cannot connect to host secure.site.here:443 ssl:None [[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1076)]
```

(actual url snipped.)

The bot itself is dockerized, running `python:3.7.4-slim-buster`. The error is not present when built with image `python:3.7.4-slim-stretch`.

I've also tested the same script built with base image `-buster` on MacOS and also a GCP Compute Engine instance, both are error free.

What am I missing? Any tips welcome.

Comment: you question is answerd here : https://serverfault.com/questions/984926/amazon-linux-2-openssl-wrong-singature-type

Comment: and here's the another solution https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4775

Answer (score 0):

First of all I checked the current tls version used by connection to the site. It was 1.2.

I got same error with `wget` so I understand that problem not in python itself, but somewhere in openssl and system settings.

On `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` I upgrade openssl from `1.1.1f` to `1.1.1g` - it solves the issue for me. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1102966/1034345) manual.