# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type with Python requests

Tags: ssl, python-requests, openssl

On a specific URL I am getting `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type` using Python's `requests` library.
I have tried the answers at [python requests : SSL error during requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631955/python-requests-ssl-error-during-requests) but they do not help.
Not even `verify=False` from, e.g., [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror), helps:

```py
url = 'https://infoteka.bg.ac.rs/ojs/index.php/Infoteka/issue/view/20'

import requests
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1131)
```

I have the most recent distribution package of openssl:

```sh
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Though I note that upgrading to 1.1.1g stated at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387377/589165 could perhaps solve the problem.

My webbrowsers do not have a problem with the particular page (as far as I can tell), while both wget and curl have the same problem as requests.

What are the options here? Would it be necessary to manually install a newer version of openssl? Or are there other possible workarounds?

Comment: *"On a specific URL"* - what kind of URL is this? Can you get the certificate for the URL? Maybe it is signed with SHA-1 or even MD5?

Comment: The URL is in the Python code: https://infoteka.bg.ac.rs/ojs/index.php/Infoteka/issue/view/20 My Firefox can display information about the certificate. It states that the signature algoritm is "SHA-384 with RSA Encryption".

Comment: I encountered another website https://www.billboard-japan.com/d_news/detail/119991 that has the same problem; neither verify=False nor changing SECLEVEL work.